# DateTime does not allow addition of milliseconds unless UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add milliseconds to a DateTime object and discovered that it is ignored, only the integer is applied (when using values over 1.0).

As you can see, using either a Time object or calling `.utc` on the DateTime produces the correct result:

```
utc_datetime = (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856).utc + 0.5.seconds).to_s(:ms_hr)
# => "2018-08-08 10:24:46.356"

non_utc_datetime = (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) + 0.5.seconds).to_s(:ms_hr)
#=> "2018-08-08 10:24:46.856"

time = (Time.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) + 0.5.seconds).to_s(:ms_hr)
#=> "2018-08-08 10:24:46.356"
```

Why? Why does a standard DateTime ignore milliseconds? What does the `.utc` call do which suddenly makes the object behave as needed?

Comment: I'm a little confused, all the outputs look the same, was this a copy-paste error?

Comment: The non_utc_datetime has added 1s instead of 0.5s. It’s on 46.856 instead of 46.356.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DateTime` and what you get from calling `.utc` on it are two different objects so when you add something to each,  each of those objects can coerce the other object as it sees fit.

`DateTime` is a DateTime object while, in rails at least calling [.utc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-utc) on a DateTime object will return a `Time` object.

In the case of DateTime, it looks like it is expecting the value after `+` to be in days,  while Time expects the value to be in seconds.

For example

```
(DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) )
2.4.1 :050 > (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) )
 => #<DateTime: 2018-08-08T10:24:45+00:00 ((2458339j,37485s,856000000n),+0s,2299161j)> 

# add 1 day
2.4.1 :051 > (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) + 1 )
 => #<DateTime: 2018-08-09T10:24:45+00:00 ((2458340j,37485s,856000000n),+0s,2299161j)> 

# add 100ms
2.4.1 :052 > (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) + 0.1/60.0/60.0/24.0)
 => #<DateTime: 2018-08-08T10:24:45+00:00 ((2458339j,37485s,956000000n),+0s,2299161j)> 

# add 1s
2.4.1 :053 > (DateTime.new(2018, 8, 8, 10, 24, 45.856) + 1.0/60.0/60.0/24.0)
 => #<DateTime: 2018-08-08T10:24:46+00:00 ((2458339j,37486s,856000000n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Another example that demonstrates what is going on:

```
2.4.1 :081 > t = Time.now
 => 2019-02-02 09:20:23 -0500 

# adding 1 to a time object adds a second
2.4.1 :082 > (t + 1).to_i - t.to_i
 => 1 

2.4.1 :083 > d = DateTime.now
 => #<DateTime: 2019-02-02T09:20:58-05:00 ((2458517j,51658s,883341147n),-18000s,2299161j)> 

# adding 1 to a DateTime object add 60*60*24 = 86400 seconds, ie 1 day
2.4.1 :085 > (d + 1).to_time.to_i - d.to_time.to_i
 => 86400
```